# Как уменьшить расстояние между обьектами?

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такие объекты, и между ними надо уменьшить расстояние между ними, но я уже подзабыл как. Подскажите?

[image]

Вот проблема, слишком большое расстояние, из-за чего они вылезают за рамки.

Вот их CSS:

```
#foto {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: -150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  right: 100px;
}
.file{
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 60px 100px 50px 130px;
}
.file_img img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;

}
```

Comment: ихний - это чеяшний?

Comment: Попробуй через **margin** сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно поняла вашу разметку, то причина в следующем: из-за того, что ширина контейнера `#foto`, в котором вы размещаете фотографии, задана динамически (`width: 100vw` - то есть, во всю ширину окна), а размеры фотографий и отступы между ними заданы жёстко в пикселях (`margin: 60px 100px 50px 130px;` у элемента с классом `.file` и `width: 200px` у `.file` и `.file_img`) - в какой-то момент ширина контейнера с чёрной рамкой (как и ширина окна) становится меньше, чем сумма ширин фотографий и расстояний между ними.

В вашем случае (как правильно заметили в комментарии) можно задать свойство `margin` для контейнеров с фото `.file` в процентах, чтобы оно не было жёстким, а регулировалось в зависимости от ширины блока. Или попробовать вовсе убрать это свойство, поскольку у контейнера с фотографиями вы прописали flex-свойство `justify-content: space-around`, что уже означает, что фотографии будут распределены так, чтобы свободное место располагалось поровну вокруг них. Если вы хотите сделать так, чтобы крайние картинки "прижимались" к краям блока `#foto`, а остальные располагались между ними с равными расстояниями - попробуйте `justify-content: space-between`.

P.S.: если вы прикрепите html-разметку этого фрагмента, то можно будет с большей точностью выяснить, что пошло не так, и дать более действенный совет:)